# Different sites for different levels of audience

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, area-51

I realized there are MathOverflow and Math.Stackexchange for different levels of audiences, and the users of both sites seem to be happy with that. I feel that with respect to programming questions, StackOverflow has wide variety of levels. On the lower end, there are questions that look like homework questions that the OP themselves do not neccesarily understand. These questions are often very sloppy, and do not fully state the question. There are also questions that are very broad, asking what textbook to read etc. On the higher end, there are well defined interesting questions. Has there been any previous discussions to split StackOverflow for different levels of audiences just like MathOverflow and Math.Stackexchange? What would be a reason for or against such suggestion?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the separation on other sides is more academic vs. non-academic? Where the SO separation you suggest would be "bad question" vs "good question". I'm not certain that is a smart move.

Answer (score 13):

Here's the problem:

> These questions are often very sloppy, and do not fully state the question.

Math.SE doesn't like crappy questions any more than MO does. Yes, they target different audiences with different expectations and different levels of expertise, but that doesn't mean MSE == "anything goes". If we created a "Stack Overflow Learners" site, half-assed questions that fail to actually describe a problem aren't going to do any better there than they do on SO right now...

...And the truth is, beginner questions that *do* clearly state a problem don't do all that badly on SO. Which raises the question, *why do we need a beginner/homework site?*

Indeed, it'd be easier to split expert-level topics out of Stack Overflow than it would be to relocate all of the low-level stuff. And on that note, you might want to check out [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) at some point...

Comment: I agree that crappy versus well stated questions would not work well as the division. How do you think about questions that just ask for what is in the doc? There are so many of them, and I frequently feel they are just flooding the site. Or questions that ask to go over each step of a fairly simple algorithm or each element of a single regex. Regarding the Programmers site, I feel it somewhat targets professionals, but I think it is for different field.

Comment: A pretty good chunk of questions on SO can be - and often are - answered just by quoting the docs. If you're talking about questions that ask for help *understanding* a bit of documentation, those are fine too *as long as the asker is specific about what he's struggling to understand.* Questions that just ask for some bit of documentation to be reiterated in different words - or which essentially ask for someone to *write* extensive documentation for some broad topic - are not going to do well anywhere. Soooo many problems on SO are caused by folks just failing to be clear about what they need

Comment: @Shog9 Are you sure? :) I thought it was because they were just trying to get other people to do their work for them, whether that means quoting the Unix Programmer’s Manual (or whatnot) to them or whether it means quoting the Oxford English Dictionary or Roget’s. When people come here first rather than trying to do their own work, it doesn’t turn out well.

Comment: Cause & effect, @tchrist: if you don't take the time to figure out what it is you don't know, you're gonna have a hard time asking someone else to provide it.